# SSMS path error: file specified for :r command was not found

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms, sqlcmd

While navigating to the given path on cmd it was working fine but I am not sure why its not working here.

```
:setvar path "C:\Users\hamid\Documents"
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'Plant') 
BEGIN 
    :r $(path)\Createplant
    PRINT 'Table Plant successfully created.' 
END 
ELSE 
    PRINT 'You already have table Plant created.' 
GO
```

But I get this error;

```
A fatal scripting error occurred.
The file specified for :r command was not found.
```

Comment: Too many backslashes? Concatenating `C:\Users\hamid\Documents\ ` and `\Createplant` will yield `C:\Users\hamid\Documents\\Createplant` - with two backslashes. Also, did you save the SQL file without any `.sql` extension?

Comment: Sorry question edited. Typo mistake.

Comment: C:\Users\hamid\Documents\Createplant
I am not sure about saving file without .sql. Can you elaborate the question. I am using SSMS

Comment: Firstly, these `:setvar` and `:r` commands are designed for the `sqlcmd` utility, they won't work in SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio). Secondly, you're instructing `sqlcmd` to load a file named `Createplant` - it's not going to find it if the file is actually named `Createplant.sql`. See [sqlcmd Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility) for general usage and [D. Using sqlcmd for database maintenance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/sqlcmd-use-the-utility#d-using-sqlcmd-for-database-maintenance) for a specific example of `:r`.

Comment: :setvar and :r will work in SSMS, as well, provided that we choose the SQLCMD mode (Under Query menu option)

Comment: No they are in sqlcmd mode. not in SSMS

Comment: It works my mistake. the file loading was problem.